# Bluetoothctl error connecting with bluetoothctl

Tags: bluetooth

I have the version bluez 5.50, and I'm trying to pair trust and connect two raspberry pi. I try with a smartphone, and I can connect between a raspberry pi and a smartphone. However, when I'm trying to connect between two raspberry I get:

```
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9F:91:A7 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9F:91:A7 Connected: no
```

Any idea?